# Prusa i3 mk3 step skipping and layer shifting

Tags: prusa-i3, layer-shifting

After approx. a year of more or less problem-free printing (40 days print time) with Prusa i3 mk3 kit, we started to suffer the random layer shifting on Y axis.

- We inspected all the motor connectors are properly inserted in the mainboard and the wires are intact.
- We ensured all the pulleys' screws on the x/y motor shafts are very tight and secure to be sure the pulleys don't slip.
- We inspected the belts and pulleys, there is no mechanical problem like dust blobs, filament residues, etc.
- We tightened the belts to be hard enough to show the expected `support|belt status` value (under 280) after `self test` is performed.
- We switched off the `crash detection` feature.
- We fully cleaned/re-lubricated the Y axis linear bearings and the rods to be sure there is no dirt causing any friction.
- We tightened the nuts on the U holders fixing the bearings to the bed (hard enough not to squeeze the bearings so they can freely move on the rods).
- We bought Japan `PNY LM8UU` bearings and replaced the original ones on Y axis (suspecting they are worn out).

Nothing of these helped fully:

- Some steps improved the quality (like only one random skip in print).
- Some steps degraded the quality (like additional step skips in previously flawless X axis).

Since the issues started, we had 4 hour reference design to be printed again and again using the same setup/filament etc. It became reference because its print started to exhibit the skips. We refused to slow down the print or perform any other workarounds, because we wanted to `make the printer great again` ;-)

**What else should have been done to revert back to flawless prints without random X/Y step skipping and thus layer shifting?**

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: **Try to replace the stock power supply.**

- We connected UPS between the printer supply and the wall outlet and the skips reduced to one/two per print.
- We replaced the supply with random old used `Mean Well SP-320` (zero care about the power panic feature, just plain 24V connected) and voilà: reference design passed.
- Also few more complex designs after supply switch are still flawless, so we hope that was the problem and it's fixed now.
- This Q&A post is to help others to skip the major frustration and save some time.